# How can i use mysqli_fetch_assoc to fix "fatal error: cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array"

Tags: php, mysql

I was getting the fatal error while trying to run mysql delete transaction so i searched for similar issues and it became obvious using mysqli_fetch_assoc is the way to fix this. Tried a couple of times but am obviously doing something wrong, would appreciate any help.

Here's my code

```
<?php  
$selected_admin = find_admin_by_id($_GET["admin"]);
if (!$selected_admin) {
    redirect_to("sadmin.php");
}

while ($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected_admin)) {
    $admin_id = $selected_admin["admin_id"];
}

$sql = "delete from admin where admin_id = {$admin_id} limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
    $SESSION["message"] = "Admin successfully deleted.";
    redirect_to("sadmin.php");
} else {
    $SESSION["message"] = "Admin was not deleted successfully.";
    redirect_to("sadmin.php?admin={$admin_id}");
}
?>
```

And the function am calling is this

```
function find_admin_by_id($admin_id) {
    global $connection;

    $query = "select * from admin where admin_id = {$admin_id} LIMIT 1";
    $current_admin = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($current_admin);
    return $current_admin;
}
```

Comment: In your while loop, `$selected_admin["admin_id"]` should be `$admin["admin_id"]`. `$selected_admin` is the result, you are getting an array from that and saving it in `$admin`. `$admin` is now an array with the current row.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn worked like magic, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong variable in while loop and my other mate also mentioned one hour ago, here is the correct code with minor changes:

```
<?php 
$selected_admin = find_admin_by_id($_GET["admin"]); 
if (!$selected_admin) { redirect_to("sadmin.php"); 
} 
while ($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected_admin)) 
{ 
$admin_id = $admin["admin_id"]; 
} 

if( intval($admin_id) > 0 ){
$sql = "delete from admin where admin_id = {$admin_id} limit 1";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) 
{ 
$SESSION["message"] = "Admin successfully deleted.";

 redirect_to("sadmin.php"); 
} 
else { 
$SESSION["message"] = "Admin was not deleted successfully."; redirect_to("sadmin.php?admin={$admin_id}"); 
}
}
 ?>
```

**What I change:**

Change $selected_admin as $admin.
And add if condition before executing DELETE STATEMENT.

Comment: thanks for the advice to add the if condition before deleting. Helps a lot.